# Grouped ListView in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to create a grouped `ListView` entirely in `XAML`? In this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx),  it is explained how to implement grouping using `CollectionViewSource`. But is something like shown below possible?

```
<ListView>
   <Group 1>
      <ListViewItem />
      <ListViewItem />
      <ListViewItem />
  </Group 1>
  <Group 2>
      <ListViewItem />
      <ListViewItem />
      <ListViewItem />
  </Group 2>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, this is not a feature in the ItemsControls in WinRT apps.  You must use the CollectionViewSource for grouping lists.